# English equivalent of Polish "An ox forgot [how it was] when it was a calf"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

"*An ox forgot [how it was] when it was a calf*" is used to describe a person that has no mercy/is harsh on someone younger when he makes a mistake. Generally speaking, the older one pretends to be Mr. Know-it-all despite the fact that he also made the same mistake, or generally made mistakes, when he was younger. How can we say the same thing in English?

**EDIT**
Because there is no direct translation: if I said this idiom to you (that has never heard it before) would you get the meaning?

Comment: Supposedly, the equivalent is "The (parish) priest forgets that he was a clerk"... but I've never heard this English idiom! http://internationalcongress.aiesec.org/2016/04/19/polish-sayings/ (Now that I've read that article, I wonder: where does "beka" come from?)

Comment: *"Remember your roots"* or something like that comes to mind.

Comment: The quite opposite proverb (forgiving young's mistakes) is "A ragged colt may make a good horse".

Comment: @NVZ 'We were all young once'.

Comment: @sumelic: I have no idea where "beka" comes from nor what it means in Polish (not even after reading that article you linked to), but in Hungarian, *béka* means "frog".

Comment: @sumelic "Beka" is a word in polish youths slang and by youth I mean also students. I use it sometimes but to be honest I don't know where it come from and I am Pole. Anyway you generally use "beka" when you want to express that something is really funny, it's equivalent to i.e. "big LOL" or "big fu*king LOL" (of course LOL is also used among youths) You want to say it in Polish? Then say "Ale beka" or "niezła beka" etc.

Comment: @Colonder: Thanks! It seems like a useful term to know. But the origin is mysterious, hmm... I found a book that seems to say it comes from *beczka* "barrel"?! https://books.google.com/books?id=jKsUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA326&lpg=PA326&dq=polish+beka+beczka&source=bl&ots=fDR_vO4Ars&sig=C31NGe4hI7kNjhwpWTMUqtdKJR8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF-P_n49zMAhWh8YMKHbG4DFQQ6AEIMTAE#v=snippet&q=beka&f=false

Comment: @sumelic Yes "beka" in Polish is "a big barrel". As I think about it now the only reasonable explanation that comes to my mind is that it is somehow connected to size of both things. I mean that a barrel is BIG and also LOL can be BIG

Comment: @sumelic talking about barrels - "beczułka" is "a tiny barrel" :)

Comment: @sumelic yeah it's nothing personal but we always laugh that English is so lame when it comes to swearing in comparison to Polish or even Russian but that's arguable :D

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're asking for something you might **say to** such a person (in which case "We were all young once" works), or whether you're looking for an expression to **describe that person who is overly judgemental** (in which case it doesn't).

Comment: @MaxWilliams well Polish is quite flexible language that is there is quite a lot "universal" phrases that can be said **to** someone and **about** someone. One of them is this expression. Every language is flexible thing in which you can say one thing in houndreds of ways. That's why there are idioms and sayings - if a picture is worth 1000 words then an idiom or saying is worth 100k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like [Edwin commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324801/english-equivalent-of-polish-an-ox-forgot-how-it-was-when-it-was-a-calf#comment739363_324801), there's this phrase I might have heard at times.

### "We were all young once"

Couldn't find any dictionary reference, but googling sure gives me some examples of it being used.

Another one that came to mind is

### "Remember your roots"

There are many variations to this and it's not a set phrase as such.

Then there's a not-so-related proverb. This does not mean the exact thing you require but can be used to imply that all beginners will make some mistakes.

### "You can't make an omelette without breaking eggs"

From [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can%27t_make_an_omelette_without_breaking_eggs)

> In order to achieve something, it is inevitable and necessary that something should be destroyed

Answer (score 2):

We have pretty much same one in S.Korea, "A frog doesn't remember those days when it was a tadpole." We use it when someone laugh at young people and how they make mistakes, as if he/she didn't make those mistakes when they were younger.

Answer (score 1):

*What's the matter with kids today?*

This, and its variants, is a common meme in US usage. There is a song in the musical, *[Bye Bye Birdie](http://www.songlyrics.com/bye-bye-birdie/kids-lyrics/)* which enshrines the phrase

> Kids, you can talk and talk till your face is blue
>
> Kids, but they still do just what they want to do
>
> Why can't they be like we were, perfect in every way?
>
> What's the matter with kids today?

Comment: After reading lyrics I get the ironic meaning but I'm afraid that if I use this one sentence alone in conversation with one that doesn't know the context of the lyrics he will understand it completely opposite to what I'd like to express. Anyway thanks for the tip

Comment: @Colonder I agree. My family knows the context, but to strangers I might repeat the last 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Though not *precisely* what you may be looking for, this **quote** possibly sums up the entire message.

> Youth cannot know how age thinks and feels. But old men are guilty if they forget what it was to be young.
>   — J. K. Rowling.

And yes, never having heard the idiom before I could grasp what you were trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

**He forgot where he came from** is used, but I think more in the sense of having come up in the world economically than having grown older.